# Rails nested attributes for many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

Hi I am trying to implement a feature using nested attributes. In the form for creating a handicap (for Customer) I would like to display a list of all the Customer's leagues and when the form is submitted in the Create action, I would use @handicap.save and this will create the association between the Handicap and Leagues as well (the leagues that were selected in the form).

The only solution I found was without using nested attributes.
In the new method I would get all the handicaps from customer and display them in the form. So when the form is submitted in the create action I would do validations.., create the @handicap record for Customer and then 
manually for each League Id that comes from the form I would create the associations.

```
#New/Create actions in the handicaps controller

def new
  @leagues = @customer.leagues
end

def create
  handicap = @customer.handicaps.build(handicap_params)
  if handicap.save
    associations = []
    params[:league_ids].each do |id|
      associations << LeagueHandicap.new(handicap_id: @handicap.id, league_id: id)
    end
    LeagueHandicap.import(associations)
  end
end
```

I would want to do handicap.save and automatically create the LeagueHandicap associations as well. However I have no clue on how to do it with nested attributes. Can it be done like this?

I have the following models:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :handicaps, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :leagues, dependent: :destroy
end

class Handicap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  has_many :league_handicaps
  has_many :leagues, through: :league_handicaps, dependent: :destroy
end

class LeagueHandicap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :handicap
  belongs_to :league
end

class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :league_handicaps
  has_many :handicaps, through: :league_handicaps, dependent: :destroy
end
```

(Many to many relationships between Handicap and League through LeagueHandicap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you permit `league_ids` rails should add them for you.  You need to tell rails it's an array though

```
def handicap_params
  params.require(:handicap).permit(league_ids: [])
end
```

Comment: And how can I display the customer @leagues in the form. So when the form is submitter, I will have sumthing like: {handicap: {info_about handicap: {}, league_ids: [1, 2, 3] }}. I find it hard to display the leagues cocorrectly in the view. I need to use sumthing like: f.fields for :leagues do |builder| ?

Comment: Something like [`collection_check_boxes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes) `f.collection_check_boxes(league_ids, League.all, :id, :name)`

Comment: Great it works! But we cant use the same method for edit right? If we use the collection_check_boxes, even if we change the checks in the update method rails wont delete last association and create new one. Is there a way to tell rails to do that as well so we don't need to hard code it?

Comment: You can, rails will add and remove the associations as necessary

Comment: It works, thank you so much! This principle is based on many to many associations? And idea where I can get more knowledge about the little things that matter?

Comment: I would look in the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: I have a strange behaviour. If there are no associations between league-handicap I cant create one. Only if there is at least one association with the same league (league_id). Then all works fine.. in controller @handicap.errors.messages = {:leagues=>["is invalid"]}.

Comment: Is the league you're trying to create the association with valid?

Comment: I found out the problem. As you suspected the league was not valid.